# How do I add a link to a macro to the Quick Access Toolbar

Tags: microsoft-access

I am trying to add a button to run a macro in Access 2007 to my Quick Access Toolbar (QAT).

In Excel 2007, I have never had an issue.  In the **Customize Quick Access Toolbar** window I can select **Macros** from *Choose Commands From* and then all my non-private macros are listed.  I can add them to my ribbon.

However, in Access 2007 nothing shows up in this list of Macros.  I feel like there is something in the fundamentals of Access and Macros I am missing but not sure what ...

Thanks for your help.

Adding module example saved as *TestModule* (see screenshots as well).  I still feel I am missing something very simple here ... *sigh*

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Public Sub HelloWorld()
    MsgBox "Hello world!"
End Sub
```

[image: 1st Screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a terminology problem.  In Excel, a "macro" is a VBA subroutine.  In Access, VBA code is NOT a "macro".  Access calls a different thing a macro, and you don't have any of that different thing.

Access macros are created by going to the Create tab on the ribbon and clicking the Macros button, and creating an ACCESS macro.

Answer (score 0):

In Access the macro's are per-database (and per-user), and what that list is showing you is the all the macro's in the currently opened DB.

So if you setup a Macro for a database, and then close it, the macro is not available in the list anymore.

Comment: In the database I have open I have `Module1` and `Module2` (under the *Module* group) which are saved with the database and contain my Macros ... but they don't show up in the list ... is that what you meant?

Comment: If the Sub's in the module are marked as `Private`, then they probably won't be available in the list;  try marking them as `Public`.  Additionally, if the Module itself is marked with `Option Private Module`, this may make them unavailable (as well).  Perhaps edit your question with information about where the macro's reside, and if possible, post an example macro you're trying to use.

Comment: Per your suggestion I added more details as well as a couple screenshots; I feel like I somehow have my hat on backwards with this one.  Thanks.